# How do I reference cells from different sheets with single combo box element?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

Let's say I have 2 sheets: `companies` and `persons`. I take companies' and persons' names and put them into a single combo box so the items in the combobox look like this:

```
*CompanyName1
*CompanyName2
*CompanyName3
...
*CompanyNameN
*PersonName1
*PersonName2
*PersonName3
...
*PersonNameN
```

I want the ComboBox to reference the corresponding cell when chosing it, but how do I do it if the entries are from 2 different cells? I only see it this way:

1. Fill ComboBox with items from `Companies`
2. Make a variable to keep the starting index of the `Persons`

   ```
    dim PersonsIndexStart as Integer
   PersonsIndexStart = ComboBox.ListCount + 1
   ```
3. Fill ComboBox with items from `Persons`
4. Upon an Item being selected calculate the "true index" of an item.

   ```
   dim TrueIndex as integer

   If ComboBox.ListIndex >= PersonsIndexStart Then
       TrueIndex = ComobBox.ListIndex - PersonsIndexStart
       Else TrueIndex = ComboBox.ListIndex
   End If
   ```

This method seem clumsy, is there another way? For example can I attach some extra data to a ComboBox item other than it's name?

Comment: Could you use a worksheet function, say `match` or `countif` so see if the selection is present on each sheet?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Returning the value of ComboBox entry and searching for it in the ranges? That might work.

Comment: Maybe you could use hidden columns with Kind (Company/Person) and Index values?

Comment: What about using a 2 column combo and loading the cell address in the second one. Making it visible or not... In this way you can access the cell without needing the combo index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Can I attach some extra data to a ComboBox?**
(example code assumes a UserForm)

Of course it's possible to fill a ComboBox with a 2-dimensional data block; multiple columns are defined by its `.ColumnCount` and `.ColumnWidths` properties. You can even hide columns by defining zero widths - c.f. `UserForm_Layout`. Furthermore I demonstrate a fast method to assign data to the ComboBox'es `.List` property via the so called array method. In order to meet your additional information needs, the 2nd and 3rd column (both hidden by zero widths) are prefilled with a reference to sheet no 1 or 2 as well as its "true" row index within the referenced worksheet.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  ' Purpose: populate ComboBox with data from 2 sheets
    doFillCombo Me.ComboBox1, Sheet1, Sheet2   ' sheets reference via their CodeName here !
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Layout()
  ' Purpose: layout combobox including hidden columns
    With Me.ComboBox1
        .ColumnCount = 3                   ' << provide for 3 columns assigned via .List
        .ColumnWidths = .Width & ";0;0"    ' << hide last columns by ZERO widths
    End With
End Sub
```

**Sub call `doFillCombo()` (called from `UserForm_Initialize`)**

```
Private Sub doFillCombo(cbo As MSForms.ComboBox, _
            ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, _
            Optional ByVal ColWs1 = "A", Optional ByVal ColWs2 = "A")
' assign data from both sheets to temporary arrays
  Dim tmp1, tmp2
  tmp1 = getData(ws1, ColWs1)
  tmp2 = getData(ws2, ColWs2)

' provide for a container array
  ReDim arr(1 To UBound(tmp1) + UBound(tmp2), 1 To 3)

' read 1st data block to container
  Dim i&
  For i = 1 To UBound(tmp1)
      arr(i, 1) = tmp1(i, 1)
      arr(i, 2) = 1                   ' refers to 1st worksheet
      arr(i, 3) = i                   ' item count in the sheet's data column
  Next i
' read 2nd data block to container
  Dim StartRow&: StartRow = UBound(arr) - UBound(tmp2) + 1
  For i = StartRow To UBound(arr)
      arr(i, 1) = tmp2(i - UBound(tmp1), 1)
      arr(i, 2) = 2                   ' refers to 2nd worksheet
      arr(i, 3) = i - UBound(tmp1)    ' item count in the sheet's data column
  Next i

' Assign data to combobox'es list property by one code line
  cbo.List = arr
End Sub
```

***Helper function called by procedure `doFillCombo`**

```
    Private Function getData(ws As Worksheet, ByVal col, Optional ByVal StartRow& = 2) As Variant()
    ' Purpose: assign column data to variant array
    If IsNumeric(col) Then col = Split(ws.Cells(1, col).Address, "$")(1)
    Dim LastRow&
    LastRow = ws.Range(col & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    getData = ws.Range(col & StartRow & ":" & col & LastRow).Value2
    End Function
```

**Possible test display to get infos**

Assumes a label control (e.g. `Label1`) displaying the referenced sheet no as well as the row index as prefilled in the hidden combobox columns:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()
' Purpose: display sheet related counters
' Note:    index reference to .List is zero-based (1st column = 0, 2nd = 1, ...)
  With Me.ComboBox1
      If .ListIndex < 0 Then Exit Sub
      Me.Label1 = "Sheet" & .List(.ListIndex, 1) & " " & _
                  "Item " & .List(.ListIndex, 2) ' optional test display via e.g. Label1
  End With
End Sub
```

BTW You won't avoid some calculations anyway; in your case I'd even suggest to stick to your chosen method, but to get indices via a user defined function - needn't to regard this as clumsy :-).

Answer (score 0):

If your second data is for example in range `A20:A50` then you can use

```
Range("A20").Offset(ComboBox.ListIndex,0)
```

to get directly to the right cell. So you just need to know where your second list begins.

Comment: The thing is, if entries from first sheet have indexes, say 0-4, and from the second sheet indexes are 5-9 then if I pick an entry with the index of `8` it will return me offset `8` when it should return me offset `4` for the 2nd sheet.